# Problems with simple Leaflet + Mapbox TitleLayer?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm completely new to GIS, and thought I would start off with the leaflet  [quick tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html). However, I'm having problems with adding the base tile layer with Mapbox. This is my code so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <title>Agricultural Trade Patterns</title> 
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 600px"></div> 
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script> 
    <script>
        //initialize the map 
        var map = L.map('map').setView([41.854501, -87.715496],13);

        L.titleLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/page.html?access_token=', {
            maxZoom:18,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            id: '',
            accessToken: ''
        }).addTo(map); 

        map.on('click', onMapClick);


    </script>
</body>
```

I tried to follow the tutorial as much as I could, but whenever I test it I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: L.titleLayer is not a function
```

And I can't figure out why. Am I passing the wrong arguments to [tileLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer)? I know my URL template doesn't have the exact format that was on the leaflet tutorial, but I couldn't find a png url like that anywhere? Is that the problem? Sorry if this is a simple question, I'm just completely new to this stuff.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Umm... Did you just paste your access token here in the code? You might want to edit it out.

Comment: @PaulJ Don't know what I was thinking, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's is no such thing as `L.TitleLayer`. It's called `L.TileLayer`:

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer